# Access variable from different js file

Tags: javascript

I Have 3 html files & 3 js files

index.html,rank.html,score.html

global.js,rank.js,score.js

In index.html I have included rank.html and score.html using iframe.

In global.js I have declare Var rank; & global.js included in rank.html & score.html.

I am updating the value of rank in rank.js and i want to access the updated value in score.js. In score.js I dont get the Updated value It gives UNDEFINED value.

I dont want to include rank.js in score.html so i created global.js & included in html file.

Here is my code,

Index.html

```
<html>
    <head>

    </head>
    <body>
<iframe src="../rank/rank.html" frameborder = "0" scrolling="no" width="50%" height = "100%"></iframe>
<iframe src="score.html" frameborder = "0" scrolling="no" width="50%" height = "100%"></iframe>

    </body>
</html>
```

global.js

```
var rank;
```

score.js

```
$(document).ready(
        function(){     


                    setInterval(dataupdate, 10000);


    });
function dataupdate() { 

alert(rank) 

};
```

rank.js

```
$(document).ready(
            function(){     


                        setInterval(dataupdate, 10000);


        });
    function dataupdate() { 

    rank = "first";

    };
```

I want updated value of rank in score.js file how to access that value...

Thanks.....

Comment: Is global.js included in index.html or both score.html and rank.html?

Comment: Post small code example illustrating your problem. An entire wall of code is hard to understand.

Comment: It is the matter of ordering your script files. Declare global.js file before you declare any file that wants to access the variable from global.js.

Comment: ok thanks.... Using parent.rank = "first" & alert(parent.rank) will solve the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you declare a global variable like you've done it gets created as a property of the `window` object, i.e `window.rank`. Your main window and the 2 iframes have separate `window` objects and therefore `window.rank` assigned from the main frame is not the same `window.rank` accessed from one of the iframes.

For accessing the rank property of the main window object from inside an iframe, you can use `parent.rank` instead of `window.rank`

Comment: Thanks , It will really useful for me... Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If global.js is included in index.html then you need to use window.top.rank (or window.parent.rank if index.html may also exist in a frame).

Answer (score 0):

You should hold the varibale in the index , cause you can only access the parent variable from iframe

```
index 

var a=5;

-----------

rank

parent.a=6
```

now score can read `parent.a` as 6

Answer (score 0):

try

```
window.parent.rank
```

or

```
window.top.rank
```